# WP-CLI alias: connect with ssh proxy

Tags: wp-cli, proxy, ssh

I have a `wp-cli.yml` file that defines an alias for a remote host:

```
@origin:
  ssh: myserver.example.com
  path: /path/to/htdocs
```

This would normally allow me to use `wp @origin command` to run remote commands on the other host. In one case, however, the remote host is only visible through an SSH proxy, so my system has an SSH config entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:22 proxyserver.example.com
    ForwardAgent yes
```

This instructs it to first connect to the proxy server, then connect from there to destination server. I can log into that box in a single step simply by typing:

```
$ ssh myserver.example.com
```

However, when I attempt the same with WP-CLI it doesn't work:

```
$ wp @origin db export --add-drop-table -
Error: Cannot connect over SSH using provided configuration.
```

I conclude that WP-CLI either doesn't look at my SSH config or doesn't understand the `ProxyCommand` directive there.

Is there anything I can add to either the `wp-cli.yml` config or the `wp` command to make it use a proxy the same way SSH does?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `myserver.example.com` in my example does not resolve to an actual IP address. It's only visible through the proxy. The alias name `@origin` is limited to wp-cli, and nothing to do with its domain name.

Comment: If I try using a short name eg `myserver`, and put the same into `~/.ssh/config`, it doesn't help.

Comment: Too bad, then I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I created simillar configuration to yours and proxy is working for me. My config looks like:

```
Host production
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:22 vagrant
  ForwardAgent yes

Host vagrant
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /path/to/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ForwardAgent yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

I'm treating my vagrant local machine as proxy and I want to execute command on production server.

My wp-cli.yml file looks like:

```
@local:
  ssh: vagrant/var/www/test

@prod:
  ssh: production/var/www/test
```

I'm executing wp command and in return I get data from my production server.

`wp @prod config get`

I know that proxy is working because if I remove `Host vagrant` section from `~/.ssh/config` file I can't execute any command and in return I get an error.

You can try install wp-cli localy using composer

`composer require wp-cli/wp-cli`

`echo` [escaped command](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/930e5b27538cb152a21b4d0de75580eefc5b8deb/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L430) variable and execute command like that:

`./vendor/bin/wp @prod config get`

This variable should contain your full ssh command. Maybe this will give you a hint what is going on.